# How can I force a program that uses the DirectXTex library to save a tga file?

Tags: c++, directx, tga, dds-format

How can I use DirectXTex (C++) to open a dds texture, work with channels (invert, swap, etc.) and save simultaneously as a dds and tga file?

I wrote the first code, but for some reason it doesn't work (it doesn't save tga):

```
#include <DirectXTex.h>

using namespace DirectX;

int main()
{
    ScratchImage    image;
    TexMetadata     metadata;

    LoadFromDDSFile(L"texture.dds", DDS_FLAGS_NONE, &metadata, image);

    metadata            = image.GetMetadata();
    const Image*    img = image.GetImage(0, 0, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < metadata.width * metadata.height; i++)
    {
        img->pixels[i * 4] = 255 - img->pixels[i * 4];
    }

    SaveToTGAFile(*img, L"texture.tga");

    return 0;
}
```

I set up the project in Visual Studio, the code compiles without errors or warnings.

Comment: Why  is it tagged `C++` & `C`? I do not see any `C` here. There are very few circumstances when it is allowed to use both

Comment: `SaveToTGAFile` has a return value. Why aren't you checking it for success or failure?

Comment: I checked, SaveToTGAFile does not return anything.

Comment: The documentation https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/TGA-I-O-Functions and the code https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/DirectXTex/DirectXTexTGA.cpp#L2326 say it does return a value.

Comment: You're not checking if the file loaded successfully either. Lots of things to go wrong that you could debug yourself. You could even copy/paste the code for saving into your code and give it a different name so you could step through line by line and see what it does. My guess is your working directory is set to somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: Error saving TGA file. HRESULT: 0x80070032